# IBM Worklight - Failed to send message com.notnoop.apns.EnhancedApnsNotification@

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I get this error when trying to send a push notification to an apple device.

```
Couldn't send message com.notnoop.apns.EnhancedApnsNotification@91c8809d
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(Unknown Source)
sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
java.io.OutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:161)
com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:46)
com.notnoop.apns.internal.AbstractApnsService.push(AbstractApnsService.java:52)
com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:36)
com.worklight.integration.notification.apns.ApplicationConnection.sendNotification(ApplicationConnection.java:84)
com.worklight.integration.notification.apns.APNSMediator.sendNotification(APNSMediator.java:85)
com.worklight.integration.notification.Mediator$4.run(Mediator.java:174)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have a production SSL certificate and my firewall didn't block the connection.

Re: Worklight version 5.0.6.
In application descriptor in the iphone section there's the correct bundle id and the correct pushsender password.

The app id is enabled to reiceive notification and i use a production ssl certificate so my p12 file's called apns-certificate-production.p12

This my own app and the notification works with android.
I'm using the same client process to handle both enviroiment and i tested succesfully the connection with apple service using telnet command

### I'm sending the notification with worklight adapter

UPDATE: after i remake the certificate some notifications now arrive but not all even if i send one

Comment: What about the push notifications sample application - can you test it with your production certificate? Can you test your own app with a sandbox certificate?

Comment: Notifications may arrive or not or arrive late, but Worklight doesn't have control on that after the notification is sent; from there on it belongs to the APN.

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your question with information about the following:

- Your Worklight version
- Some background on the project - is this the sample app or your own?
- How did you setup the project in application-descriptor.xml?
- How are you sending the notification?
- How did you create your push-enabled certificate?
- Did you make sure to create an App ID with push notifications capabilities?
- What name did you give the .p12 file - `apnscertificate-sandbox.p12` or `apnscertificate-production.p12`?
- Did you make sure your network is open to connections to and from Apple's APN servers as specified? (See **page 44** in the [Push Notifications training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/09_04_Push_notifications.pdf))